# What is the point of having a key_t if what will be the key to access shared memory is the return value of shmget()?

Tags: c, unix, shared-memory, ftok

When using shared memory, why should we care about creating a key

```
key_t ftok(const char *path, int id);
```

in the following bit of code?

```
key_t key;
int shmid;

key = ftok("/home/beej/somefile3", 'R');
shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
```

From what I've come to understand, what is needed to access a given shared memory is the `shmid`, not the key. Or am I wrong? If what we need is the `shmid`, what is the point in not just creating a random key every time?

### Edit

@[Beej's Guide to Unix IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mq.html#mqftok) one can read:

> What about this `key` nonsense? How do
>   we create one? Well, since the type
>   `key_t` is actually just a `long`, you can
>   use any number you want. But what if
>   you hard-code the number and some
>   other unrelated program hardcodes the
>   same number but wants another queue?
>   The solution is to use the `ftok()`
>   function which generates a key from
>   two arguments.

Reading this, it gives me the impression that what one needs to attach to a shared-memory block is the key. But this isn't true, is it?

Comment: You might prefer POSIX shared memory to SySV one. See [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the shmid to access the shared memory (using `shmat()`) after you've opened it using `shmget()`. But the specific block of shared memory that you'll be accessing is based on the key that you are using i.e. different process wishing to communicate via the shm will need to use the same key. If you just used a random number as a key, you might get a clash with some other unrelated program.

I was going to suggest taking a look at [Beej's Guide to IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/single/bgipc.html) but I see you've already found it :)

Answer (score 16):

The whole System V IPC system is full of bad designs like this. (By bad designs, I mean a tiny namespace for shared resources where you have to rely on stupid tricks like `ftok` to get a key and pray it doesn't happen to conflict with any other keys in use.)

If possible, I would pretend it doesn't exist and use POSIX shared memory instead whenever possible (and likewise POSIX thread synchronization primitives in place of System V semaphores). The only instance I can think of where you need System V shared memory is for the X shared-memory image extension and perhaps other X extensions.

**Edit:** To better answer OP's question about the purpose of `ftok`: `key_t` is usually 32-bit and yes you could just pick a 32-bit number yourself, but the problem is that humans are not equally likely to pick all numbers, and the chance of collision is way too high. `ftok` lets you choose a file (intended to be one unique to your application) and an integer and hash the file's inode number with your chosen integer, which should result in much more even distribution of key choices across the key space. Of course you could also just choose a key with `rand` as long as you have a way of passing the result to other processes that need to attach the shared memory.

Comment: If you have a "way of passing the result to other processes," it might be better just to use that for IPC or create an `IPC_PRIVATE` shared memory segment and pass the id for that around.

Comment: You strengthen my belief that the `ftok` generated key from a filename can be a duplication of another key generated from another filename. So an IPC mechanism using "Message Queue" is not 100% reliable! May be 99.9% but not 100%, that un-deterministic behavior is not what we accept in computer system. May be once in blue-moon, when there is key collision, system would be misbehave and its hard to debug such issue.

Comment: So with this understanding then, we should not use all the IPC solutions which relies on this way of key - ie Message Queue (msgget), Shared Memory (shmget) and Semaphores (semget), isnt it?

Comment: What's "X extensions"?

Answer (score 1):

`shmid` values are only valid in the context of a single process, whereas the same `key_t` value in different processes will allow them to open the same shared memory segment.

That's essentially why you need a `key_t` - as a cross-process way of naming a shared memory segment.  As for `ftok()`, as the other answers have noted, that's used to reduce the probability of two *unrelated* groups of processes using the same `key_t` value.

Comment: That's not true AFAIK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095076/is-shmid-returned-by-shmget-unique-across-processes

Comment: This is not true- you can totally bypass shmget if you have the shmid via other means, i.e. shmat(shmid, ...)